# I wanted to run a batch file which runs SQL developer query and exports in excel

Tags: excel, batch-file, oracle-sqldeveloper

I wanted to create a batch file which runs SQL developer query and exports the data result in excel however after using SQLPLUS command to run the query it does not give the excel file in the format I need and the output is not in the correct tabular form as it is when the data result of a query is exported from a sqldevloper to an excel sheet.

SQLPLUS username/password@wef:1521/wefdewTEXT.XLS

Can anyone please help with some links or info on such a kind of issue